# Evaluation of existing map cache servers

Tags: geowebcache, tilecache, mapproxy, tile-server, mapcache

there are so many different caching servers around:

- MapCache
- MapProxy
- GeoWebCach
- TileCache
- Tile-Server
- and maybe more.

I just wondering that I cannot find an evaluation or feature comparison of them on the web. Does someone bench-mark or compared some of them?

Comment: As it stands I think your question is too broad.  Each entry in a matrix of product by attribute would itself constitute a question in our focussed Q&A format and so you are asking for potentially 45 questions to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Go for MapProxy.

I used TileCache and GeoWebCache in the past and Mapproxy is far better.

1. Great performances and small footprint
2. Quite simple to understand and configure
3. You can by-pass Mapproxy with NGINX if you map your cache directory as a web directory. Calling Mapproxy only in cache-miss case.
4. Project is very active
5. Few bugs

Some example of what is possible with Mapproxy (from my own blog) : http://xavierraffin.com/2016/12/17/Custom-webmap-from-multiple-images

This map is build with Mapproxy, you can appreciate the performance (single webserver in Toulouse France) : http://www.tisseo.fr/en/interactive-map

Comment: Please note if you want to promote your own product/blog you **must disclose your affiliation**, otherwise your answer may be flagged as spam. Please read [How to not be a spammer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/promotion)

Comment: I am not affiliated to Mapproxy. I just like the tool and use it in a lot of projects.

Comment: That may be, but you are promoting your own website/blog. You **must** say that it is yours.

Comment: Is it better now?

Comment: That's perfect ... :)